# Variable declared in data() is Undefined in Listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ethereum, metamask

I am declaring a "userid" variable in the data() section of my component. Within a mounted() method, I am initiating a listener for MetaMask. Upon changing account in MetaMask this listener is triggered. However, the "userid" (declared in data()) within the listener is undefined.

```
 export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
   return {
    userid: null
   }
 },
 mounted () {
 ...
 // MetaMask Listener
 window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
  this.userid = accounts
 })
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Turn data into an arrow function so that you can use "this" in the correct context.

Comment: Thank you Martin. However, I am using the very same variable (this.userid) using the current data function elsewhere in the mounted method. I am only encountering the issue within the listener, which is obviously triggered after having previously loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue runs in `strict` mode. That means that `this` is binded to regular function itself.

You have 3 ways to solve this problem:

Use arrow function:

```
 window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', accounts => {
  this.userid = accounts
 })
```

Use `.bind()`

```
 window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
  this.userid = accounts
 }.bind(this))
```

Declare a variable outside and assign `this` to it:

```
 var self = this;
 window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
  self.userid = accounts
 })
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much Ifaruki. This has indeed solved my issue.

Comment: @JF0001 no problem